# Using 24-bit address space on 32 bit architecture

Tags: javascript, memory-address, typed-arrays

Wondering how you would use 24 bit addresses in JavaScript if there are only 8, 16, and 32-bit typed arrays. I'm thinking of doing 8-bit aligned / typed array and then grabbing 3 values and summing them to get the final 24-bit address. Wondering if that is the right approach or there is a better way to do it, or more correct way.

Comment: Summing them? Why wouldn't you shift them? In any case, why can't you use 32 bits and ignore the upper byte? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not sure how to combine them. I have 32 bit architecture but 16 bits of flags, so 2 32 = 64 - 16 = 48 / 2 = 24.

Comment: Why do you need them to be exactly 24 bit? If you need to save every last bit of memory, JS might not be a good language

Comment: I don't want to waste a lot of bits and in my case it can easily expand to wasting 1/3 or 1/4 space which seems like a lot, so I am playing with ideas and want to see how 24 bits would work out. More of a learning exercise.